# How much longer does it take to mine blocks underwater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed that when my feet aren't firmly placed on the ground, it takes a significantly longer time to mine blocks, even with high-end tools. Is there a factor that mining time is increased by for these conditions? If so, what is it?

Comment: "when my feet aren't firmly placed on the ground" → well, you can mine while on a ladder. I'm pretty sure this qualifies as you describe, but it still mines fast enough. Maybe you want to reword your question... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mining while underwater or swimming takes 5 times as long.

Comment: But note that it only happens if you are underwater. If you mine a block that is underwater, but you are off the water, then there is no speed penalty.