# Movement and digging/mining speed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have noticed that when falling/climbing on ladders/submerged in water/swimming while mining/digging/chopping wood the speed at which blocks are destroyed is greatly reduced.

What kinds of movement specifically cause this slowdown, and to what degree?

**Edit:** Because in retrospect it wasn't entirely clear: What kinds of movement do *not* cause a slowdown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The circumstances under which your mining rate will slow are:

- Falling
- On a ladder
- In water or lava, unless standing in water/lava 1 block deep

Under these circumstances it takes [5 times as long](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10570/how-much-longer-does-it-take-to-mine-blocks-underwater-or-while-airborne) to mine each block than it would normally.

Comment: Am I to understand by virtue of the omission that lateral movement does *not* affect speed?

Comment: @Williham I haven't actually tried (goes off to test).

Comment: @Williham It does **not** affect mining speed. Both holding down a key while another block impedes your movement, and jigging back and forth do not change mining speed. Moving in a straight line is untestable, since no block is minable in the short time you have while you pass it.

Comment: @fredley: Well, actually… When I sneak and move laterally past a row of smooth stone with a diamond pickaxe while hacking away; they all fall down.

Comment: @Williham True, I just did some tests with hand/sand while sneaking laterally, no change in mining speed.

Comment: Awesometastic! Feel free to incorporate our little exchange into the answer. :)